# Small switch with a button top for gliding over?

Tags: switches

I wonder if there's a kind of switch for low voltage devices (~3V) that allows small nipples to glide over. For instance, I have a small plastic rod with small nipples (~1-2mm high) and I'd like to count the number of nipples glided over the switch position.

I've looked at some microswitches, but they all tend to be rather large (at least 2cm long). I think rounded top switches like [this lego one](http://www.bricklink.com/SL/9911-1.jpg) might work, but the lego block itself is fairly big. A ~5mm package would be great. SMD would be even better.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I'd like to count the number of nipples **glided** over the switch position". How much pressure can the rod+nipples apply to the switch?

Comment: Basically a rod with nipples is pushed along a track. The force exerted is rather small since the nipples will only rub against the switch. Probably around 1N.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would these work mechanically: -

[image]

[image]

If "maybe" then try [this](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=4+pin+tactile+switch+pcb+mount&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX_vyQ6-_JAhXBKQ8KHQ6_DyQQsAQIPg&biw=1285&bih=926#imgrc=_) link - I googled "4 pin tactile switch pcb mount" and looked at the images.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a non-mechanical solution.

'Gliding' while applying enough force for a mechanical switch, other than some microswitches, might be problem.

You might use an optical sensor. For example these [Sub-miniature Photo-reflective Sensors](http://www.rapidonline.com/Electronic-Components/Sub-miniature-Photoreflective-Sensors-68052) which contain both an IR emitter and a phototransistor in a single package about 1.5mm thick.

You may be able to make it even more effective, if you can modify the rod i.e make the rod opaque, or colour it white, with the nipples dark or opaque.

They are designed to sense at about 1mm. If you can arrange the mechanics so that the nipple separates the emitter side from the phototransistor side when it 'touches' you may be able to get a low-friction, and positive switch effect.

However, this approach would likely need more electronics than a simple mechanical switch.